# vim method to highlight longer lines

Tags: vim, command

On [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_long_lines), I've found this pattern

```
/\%>80v.\+
```

that helps in identifying lines longer than 80 characters by highlighting the characters after column 80.

I fail to understand its bit by bit explanation. Could you help me?

Comment: Oh, you could also use this to match lines with at least 81 characters: ```/.\{81\}.*```. I find this easy to remember.

Comment: @steffen: Not exactly. A character does not necessarily occupy a single display cell (think <Tab> or Asian characters). The virtual column `\%v` matches cell width, your `.` atom characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple, actually.

- `\%>80v` starts the match *after* the virtual column number 80, see `:help %>`.
- `.\+` matches 1 or more of any character, see `:help /.` and `:help \+`.

Comment: that was a nice explanation.
does virtual column mean tab counts as single character instead of 8 cells as seen on page ?

Comment: No. virtual columns count tabs as x characters. Assuming a `tabwidth` of 8 and a line consisting of `<tab><tab>abc` with the cursor on `a`: `:echo col('.')` returns `3` and `:echo virtcol('.')` returns `17`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to your posed question rather than an answer.  Hope that's ok.

You can also look into `colorcolumn`.

```
set colorcolumn=81,82,83
```

Will highlight the three characters after column 80.  If you use `textwidth` then you can also use relative values (cool if your textwidth changes for different files):

```
set textwidth=80
set colorcolumn=+1,+2,+3
```

Of course you can have as few or as many values as you want separated by columns.  I don't think it takes ranges though or "open sets" to "highlight from column N to the end of line."

The color itself is defined by the `ColorColumn` group so you can change it easily if it's too garish.

The reason why I suggest this is that it operates even if you're using search for finding things.  :)